# How can i make this shorter?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Populate()
  Dim Worksh As Worksheet
  Dim Cell As Range
  Set Worksh = Sheets("Serial Numbers")
  customer = "EXELON"
'*********************** Populate Serial Number ********************
'*******************************************************************

  JobTT = 10080
        With Worksh.Range("E7")
            .AutoFill .Resize(JobTT, 1), xlFillSeries
        End With
        With Worksh.Range("F7")
                   '.Value = cus_strt_num
                   .AutoFill .Resize(JobTT, 1), xlFillSeries
         'Range("mycell").Select
        Select Case customer
               Case "EXELON"
        For Each Cell In Range("mycell")
            If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then _
            Cell = "DARG2" & Cell
        Next Cell
               Case "AEP"
        For Each Cell In Range("mycell")
            If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then _
            Cell = "1ND" & Cell & "NMD06"
        Next Cell
        End Select

        End With

        With Worksh.Range("D7")
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D127")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D126") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
         With Worksh.Range("D247")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D146") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D367")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D366") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D487")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D486") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D607")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D606") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D727")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D726") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
         With Worksh.Range("D847")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D846") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D967")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D966") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D1087")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1086") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D1207")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1206") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D1327")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1326") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D1447")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1446") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
          With Worksh.Range("D1567")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1566") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D1687")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1686") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D1807")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1806") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D1927")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D1926") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2047")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2046") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2167")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2166") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2287")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2286") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2407")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2406") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2527")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2526") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2647")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2646") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
       With Worksh.Range("D2767")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2766") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
        With Worksh.Range("D2887")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D2886") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

         With Worksh.Range("D3007")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3006") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D3127")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3126") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D3247")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3246") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D3367")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3366") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D3487")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3486") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D3607")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3606") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D3727")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3726") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
           With Worksh.Range("D3847")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3846") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D3967")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D3966") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D4087")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4086") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

           With Worksh.Range("D4207")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4206") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D4327")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4326") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D4447")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4446") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D4567")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4566") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D4687")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4686") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D4807")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4806") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D4927")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D4926") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
           With Worksh.Range("D5047")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5046") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
           With Worksh.Range("D5167")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5166") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

            With Worksh.Range("D5287")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5286") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D5407")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5406") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D5527")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5526") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D5647")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5646") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D5767")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5766") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D5887")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D5886") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
            With Worksh.Range("D6007")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6006") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
         With Worksh.Range("D6127")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6126") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D6247")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6246") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With


             With Worksh.Range("D6367")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6366") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D6487")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6486") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D6607")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6606") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D6727")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6726") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D6847")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6846") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D6967")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D6966") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D7087")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7086") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7207")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7206") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7327")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7326") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7447")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7446") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7567")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7566") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7687")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7686") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7807")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7806") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D7927")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D7926") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D8047")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8046") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D8167")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8166") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D8287")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8286") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D8407")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8406") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D8527")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8526") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D8647")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8646") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With


             With Worksh.Range("D8767")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8766") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With


             With Worksh.Range("D8887")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D8886") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

             With Worksh.Range("D9007")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9006") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With


             With Worksh.Range("D9127")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9126") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D9247")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9246") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D9367")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9366") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D9487")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9486") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D9607")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9606") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With
             With Worksh.Range("D9727")
             .Value = Worksh.Range("D9726") + 1
             .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues

        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work? if it does and you only want to shorten it, then move this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  If it does not work then explain more what it is supposed to do and what it is doing that is in error.

Comment: But I would recommend a For loop that steps 120.

Comment: it does and you only want to shorten it

Comment: Then move to [CodeReview].  But as I said look into a For Loop: `For i = 7 to 9726 Step 120` before posting there and if you cannot make it work come back here for specific help on that.

Comment: Give your post a title that describes the purpose of the code, *describe what "this" does*, present your code, the problem it's solving, and describe what you deem the problematic areas are in a [codereview.se] question, and you'll have a great post. On this site (SO) however, this is *too broad* a question.

Comment: Mainly I want D column the to resize at 120 as many time as JobTT/120. example if JobTT= 10080 then 10080/120 =84.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the bulk of it could be replaced with:

```
Dim rw as Long

With Worksh.Range("D7")
     .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues
End With
For rw = 127 To 9727 Step 120
    With Worksh.Cells(rw, 4)
        .Value = Worksh.Cells(rw - 1, 4).Value + 1
        .AutoFill .Resize(120, 1), xlFillValues
    End With
Next
```